# Determining when fragment no longer visible in ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager2

I am looking to migrate from `ViewPager` to `ViewPager2`.  My existing `ViewPager` contains `ListFragment`s that support bulk editing via an `ActionMode`.  I need to cancel the current bulk editing operation when the user swipes from one page to another, so that the context header from one page isn't shown when viewing a different page.

With `ViewPager`, I can override `setPrimaryItem` in the `ListFragment`'s `FragmentPagerAdapter` to know when one page replaces another.  Crucially, this function takes as a parameter the actual child fragment that's becoming visible, which I can store in the adapter and later use to cancel bulk editing when it is replaced by another fragment.

How do I do the same thing with `ViewPager2`, namely, know when a fragment is no longer visible?  I have tried overriding `Fragment.onPause`, but that's not what I want---it gets called whenever the phone screen turns off or the orientation changes, and I don't want to cancel bulk editing in these circumstances.  I also have a callback registered via `ViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback`, but this gives me only the index of the new fragment, not the fragment itself or anything about the old fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution is to register a `FragmentTransactionCallback`. Downside - this was only added in [the latest 1.1.0 alpha release](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.1.0-alpha01) of the ViewPager2 library.

There's a method on that class (`FragmentTransactionCallback::onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated`) which is called whenever the `ViewPager2` changes [a Fragment's maximum Lifecycle state](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#setMaxLifecycle(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle.State)).

```kotlin
val basicAdapter: FragmentStateAdapter = // ....

basicAdapter.registerFragmentTransactionCallback(object : FragmentTransactionCallback() {
    override fun onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated(fragment: Fragment, max: Lifecycle.State): OnPostEventListener {
        // Check whether a Fragment is going to move from 'resumed' to 'started'
        //
        // Note that this check won't catch some types of smooth scroll:
        // I'm not certain why, but I think it has to do with fragments
        // already being paused before the method is called.
        //
        if (max == Lifecycle.State.STARTED && fragment.isResumed) {
            // This fragment WAS the 'current item' but it's offscreen now.
            return OnPostEventListener { TODO("Cancel Bulk Editing") }
        }
        return super.onFragmentMaxLifecyclePreUpdated(fragment, max)
    }
})
```